# Select not populating with values from WP_Query

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm trying to use values from a CPT in my query to populate a `<select>` and the CPT has data, it displays in the select, but it is the same post nine times rather than each post displaying once, so I am legitimately confused. My query and foreach are as below.

```
<select id="wooaddresslist" name="wooaddresslist" class="form-control form-control-sm">
        <option>Please select an option</option>
        <?php
            $posts = array();
            $args = array('post_type'=>'addressbook');
            $query = New WP_query($args);
            if($query->have_posts()):while($query->have_posts()):$query->the_post();

                    $temp = array();
                    $temp['id'] = get_the_id();
                    $temp['fname'] = get_field('fname');
                    $temp['lname'] = get_field('lname');
                    $temp['company'] = get_field('company');
                    $temp['addr1'] = get_field('address_line_1');
                    $temp['addr2'] = get_field('address_line_2');
                    $temp['city'] = get_field('city');
                    $temp['state'] = get_field('state');
                    $temp['zip'] = get_field('zip');
                    $posts = $temp;

                    $id         = $posts['id'];
                    $fname      = $posts['fname'];
                    $lname      = $posts['lname'];
                    $company    = $posts['company'];
                    $addr1      = $posts['addr1'];
                    $addr2      = $posts['addr2'];
                    $city       = $posts['city'];
                    $state      = $posts['state'];
                    $zip        = $posts['zip'];

                    if(!empty($posts)){
                        foreach($posts as $post){?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $id;?>"><?php echo $fname;?></option>
                        <?php }
                    }
            endwhile;endif;wp_reset_postdata();
        ?>
</select>
```

What I end up getting is

```
<select id="wooaddresslist" name="wooaddresslist" class="form-control form-control-sm">
    <option>Please select an option</option>
    <option value="136">John</option>
    <option value="136">John</option>
    <option value="136">John</option>
    <option value="136">John</option>
    <option value="136">John</option>
    <option value="136">John</option>
    <option value="136">John</option>
    <option value="136">John</option>
    <option value="136">John</option>
</select>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified version of your code that should set you on the right track.  At a glance, I think a few things were happening: I suspect your temporary arrays were just getting overwritten at the end of the loop, so in the end you were just getting a bunch of copies of the final entry in the loop. Also, just to avoid confusion, I renamed your custom `WP_query` to $address_book_query.

```
<select id="wooaddresslist" name="wooaddresslist" class="form-control form-control-sm">
<option>Please select an option</option>
    <?php
        $args = ['post_type'=>'post'];
        $address_book_query = New WP_query($args);
        if($address_book_query->have_posts()) : while($address_book_query->have_posts()) : $address_book_query->the_post();
                $address_book_entry = [];
                $address_book_entry['id'] = get_the_id();
                $address_book_entry['fname'] = get_field('fname');
                $address_book_entry['lname'] = get_field('lname');
                $address_book_entry['company'] = get_field('company');
                $address_book_entry['addr1'] = get_field('address_line_1');
                $address_book_entry['addr2'] = get_field('address_line_2');
                $address_book_entry['city'] = get_field('city');
                $address_book_entry['state'] = get_field('state');
                $address_book_entry['zip'] = get_field('zip');

    ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $address_book_entry['id'];?>"><?php echo $address_book_entry['fname'];?></option>
    <?php
        endwhile;
        endif;
        wp_reset_query();
    ?>
</select>
```